# Why does this unit test not cover my property setter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit

I am writing unit test cases using NUnit. While testing this property I get coverage for the getter, but not the setter. Why?

```
private string name = null;

public string Name
{
    get { return this.name; }
    set
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.StartsWith("@"))
        {
            name = value.Remove(0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
[Test]
public void TestNameHaveValue()
{
    classobject.Name = "@test";
    //Assert
}
```

Comment: `I can access only setter part. How can I access setter part?` What is that mean?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't trying to access `name` rather than `Name`? You should *absolutely* be able to use `Name` here. Please show a sample unit test which fails to compile.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to access the getter?

Comment: while i debug my unit test, it only cover get { return this.name; } & not the set part. And i am unit testing Name.

Comment: Can you post your entire unit test please?

Comment: Are you trying to mock you setter?

Comment: here is my unit test   [Test]
  public void TestNameHaveValue()
  {
   classobject.Name = "@test";
   //Assert
  }

Comment: @Ninad and why are you thinking getter not works? If there is no exception in your assertion, than getter is executed.

Comment: I think you're talking about code coverage?  You just need to put in something like `Assert.AreEqual("test", classObject.Name);`

Comment: What is classObject, is it an actual instance or mock?

Comment: Yes i talking about code coverage. But i am confused because debugger never go on set part. It only cover get part. Thats why set part is uncovered. I want to cover it.

Comment: Please include the test setup of `classObject`.

Comment: And for the future: When you're asking this kind of question, please include *all* relevant details in a small, concise example of code, easily reproducing your issue. As it is, we're having to drag the information bit by bit from you.

Comment: @J. Steen: classobject means i am just calling that property.            ReportParameterDTO dto = new ReportParameterDTO();
   dto.Name = "@test"; i am writing tests in anather class

Comment: The reason I asked is because you're talking about mocks, and I don't see a single line of mocking code here. What does rhinomocks have to do with any of this?

Comment: @J. Steen: should i use here rhinomock ? i thought it is not important.

Comment: @Ninad please share? You have us all mystified.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, from your comments - that you mean you're not getting code coverage on the getter of this class.  Well, you won't - because you're not reading the property value.

You need to assert something like:

```
Assert.AreEqual("test", classObject.Name);
```

After you make the assignment.

Comment: @Jonathan As it seems, that is unlikely to change any time soon... =)

Comment: J.Steen and @Jonathan - For the record this question actually has me utterly mystified...  One of those ones where you wonder if it shouldn't just be dumped in a few days...

Comment: I was hesitant to post anything because I thought it might be heading that way, looks like its garnered a -1 :)